# R言語で、判別分析（LDA）を用いた画像データの２値化法を実行する際の MASS パッケージの関数 lda() の使用法について

Tags: r, 機械学習

R言語にて、判別分析（LDA）を用いてグレースケールの画像データを２値化画像するコードを検討中です。
これを実現するにあたり、MASSパッケージの`lda()`関数を使用しようと考えてるのですが、`lda()`関数使用時エラーが発生し、その原因が分かりません。このエラーの意味と対策を教えて頂きたいですm(__)m

`lda()`関数のヘルプファイル：
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/lda.html

変換対象画像ファイル（グレースケール）
[image: nekosensei_greyscale.jpg]

以下、実装中コードです。

```
#install.packages("lda")
#install.packages("jpeg")

# expand lib on memory
library( MASS )   # MASS package
library( jpeg )   # jpeg画像の読み込み

# set options
options( digits=7 ) # 表示桁数

# load image data (jpeg)
jpeg_NekoSensei <- readJPEG( "nekosensei_greyscale.jpg" ) # 560*420 = 235200    pixel
class( jpeg_NekoSensei ) # 3次元配列 um[1:420, 1:560, 1:3]

########################################
# convert to thresholding/binary image #
########################################
dfNekoSensei <- as.data.frame( jpeg_NekoSensei ) # convert to data frame
dat_level <- seq( from=min(dfNekoSensei), to=max(dfNekoSensei), length = length(dfNekoSensei$V1) )

dat_ida <- lda( dat_level ~ . , data = dfNekoSensei ) # **この箇所でエラーが発生します**
```

エラー内容

> Error in lda.default(x, grouping, ...) :    variables    1    2 
>   3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16  
>   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30  
>   31   32   33   34   35   36   37   38   39   40   41   42   43   44  
>   45   46   47   48   49   50   51   52   53   54   55   56   57   58  
>   59   60   61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68   69   70   71   72  
>   73   74   75   76   77   78   79   80   81   82   83   84   85   86  
>   87   88   89   90   91   92   93   94   95   96   97   98   99  100 
>   101  102  103  104  105  106  107  108  109  110  111  112  113  114 
>   115  116  117  118  119  120  121  122  123  124  125  126  127  128 
>   129  130  131  132  133  134  135  136  137  138  139  140  141  142 
>   143  144  145  146  147  148  149  150  151  152  153  154  155  156 
>   157  158  159  160  161  162  163  164  165  166  167  168  169  170 
>   171  172  173  174  175  176  177  178  179  180  181  182  183  184 
>   185  186  187  188  189  190  191  192  193  194  195  196

以下、コードの続き

```
print( dat_ida )


############################
# set graphics parameters  #
############################
# 軸に関してのデータリスト
lstAxis <- list(                        
  xMin = 0.0, xMax = 1.0,  # x軸の最小値、最大値
  yMin = 0.0, yMax = 1.0,  # y軸の最小値、最大値
  zMin = 0.0, zMax = 1.0,  # z軸の最小値、最大値
  xlim = range( c(0.0, 1.0) ), 
  ylim = range( c(0.0, 1.0) ), 
  zlim = range( c(0.0, 1.0) ),
  mainTitle = "mainTitle", # 図のメインタイトル（図の上）
  subTitle  = "subTitle",  # 図のサブタイトル（図の下）
  xlab      = "x", # x軸の名前
  ylab      = "y", # y軸の名前
  zlab      = "z"  # z軸の名前
)
lstAxis$xMin <- 0
lstAxis$xMax <- 560
lstAxis$yMin <- 0
lstAxis$yMax <- 420
lstAxis$xlim = range( c(lstAxis$xMin, lstAxis$xMax) )
lstAxis$ylim = range( c(lstAxis$yMin, lstAxis$yMax) )
lstAxis$zlim = range( c(lstAxis$zMin, lstAxis$zMax) )
lstAxis$xlab <- "x1"
lstAxis$ylab <- "x2"
lstAxis$mainTitle <- "ねこ先生（グレースケール）[Greyscale]" # 図のメインタイトル（図の上）

# plot frame only
par(new=F)
plot.new()  # clear
plot( c(), type='n',
      main = lstAxis$mainTitle,
      xlim=lstAxis$xlim, ylim=lstAxis$ylim,
      xlab=lstAxis$xlab, ylab=lstAxis$ylab
)
#grid() #グリッド線を追加

############################
# Draw Image and figure    #
############################
# draw original image
rasterImage( 
  image = jpeg_NekoSensei, 
  xleft = lstAxis$xMin, xright = lstAxis$xMax, 
  ybottom = lstAxis$yMin, ytop = lstAxis$yMax
)

# draw converted image
lstAxis$mainTitle <- "ねこ先生（２値化処理後）"  # 図のメインタイトル（図の上）
plot( c(), type='n',
      main = lstAxis$mainTitle,
      xlim=lstAxis$xlim, ylim=lstAxis$ylim,
      xlab=lstAxis$xlab, ylab=lstAxis$ylab
)
rasterImage(
  image = jpeg_NekoSensei, # 変換後のデータ（とりあえず元データをセット） 
  xleft = lstAxis$xMin, xright = lstAxis$xMax, 
  ybottom = lstAxis$yMin, ytop = lstAxis$yMax
)
```

Comment: DF化が上手く出来ているようには思えません (1pixelあたり3データなのですから、235200行3列＋index、ないし705600行1列＋indexのDFが適切だと考えます)。また`lda()`は教師あり学習用関‌​数なので、`lda( dat_level ~ ...` の`dat_level`には二値データ(白 or 黒)が入らなくてはなりません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！原因＄理屈理解できました。感謝致します！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cuttlefish44](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/15653/cuttlefish44) 様のコメントのアドバイスを元に解決することが出来ました！どうもありがとうございました！又、誤記を修正くださった方々どうもありがとうございましたm(__)m

> 以下、主な修正箇所のRコード

```
########################################
# convert to thresholding/binary image #
########################################
dfNekoSensei <- as.data.frame( expand.grid(jpeg_NekoSensei) ) # convert to data frame
dat_levels <- c(
  rep( min(dfNekoSensei$Var1), length(dfNekoSensei$Var1)/2 ), 
  rep( max(dfNekoSensei$Var1), length(dfNekoSensei$Var1)/2 ) 
) # binary data set (0 or 1)

dat_lda <- lda( dat_levels ~ . , data = dfNekoSensei )
```

> 以下、修正後の実装結果
>   [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
>   [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
>   [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]